# Ember.js form on submit not working within a component modal

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to handle a form submit within a modal component seen here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oPEpuQiv/1/edit.  That code is a modified version of the Emberjs cookbook docs example seen here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/iluLOto/1/edit.

As you can see in that jsbin, nothing happens when you try to submit the form after opening the modal.  If you remove the on="submit", the form action occurs, but likely because of a click or some other event.  Am I missing something?  Is it something to do with the component?  It seems this example (http://jsbin.com/eQOZoGe/3/edit) works fine, and that's just a normal form.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give an exact answer, I'm still investigating, but it's related to having actions in the component's templates

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oPEpuQiv/15/edit

Is there any reason you don't want to use the action on the button?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) action on the button doesn't handle a user pressing 'Enter', 2) it just feels like the right way :)

I've opened up an issue on the GitHub repo after speaking with @fivetanley.  It can be found here https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4084

Comment: Yes a form tag should be used, not only as it would be required for accessibility but in case there are other fields. The form, not each field, should dectate how to respond to submit. As of 1.8.0-beta.5 I'm seeing odd behavior with forms inside of components as well. A click on an input field gets mapped into a submit without an action, when the form has action assigned to something else.